# How to stream TV/Films/Music over the internet to various devices from a home server?

Tags: video, internet, streaming, media, home-server

Set up:
An always on old-ish laptop connected to a NAS which contains TV/Films/Music.

I want to be able to stream on the fly the data on my NAS to various connected devices such as iphone or laptop. I am currently using Orb (orb.com) mycast software but the requirements for the streaming are very high in terms of processing power is there alternative software and dedicated hardware i can add to get maximum benefit from this setup?

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can be setup to [stream video](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) at various bit rates

Some examples of using it to stream to the iphone here:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/10/23/how-to-set-vlc-player-as-media-server-to-stream-media-files-in-digital-home/

http://www.winandmac.com/mobile/vlc-on-iphone-makes-flash-and-live-video-streaming-has-come-true/

http://pietervangils.com/iphone/how-to-convert-avi-to-mp4-for-iphone-with-vlc/

http://iphone3g-india.com/vlc-player-does-movie-and-radio-streaming-on-iphone/

Comment: the problem with vlc is you have to set up vlc to stream the video you want - there is no ability to browse from the remote location.