# Networking with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, sync, windows-media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

I got several computers connected to my home wireless network and I want to make use of some of the features of Windows 7 for home networks but I can't seem to get them working:

1. How do I keep files and folders in sync between specific computers? I'm not talking about Live Sync.
2. How can I stream to Windows Media Player from another computer?

I would appreciate if someone could provide me some links / solutions that address my needs. Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/117417/how-to-stream-audio-and-video-files-but-use-any-media-player-on-windows-without http://superuser.com/questions/28463/how-to-stream-tv-films-music-over-the-internet-to-various-devices-from-a-home-ser

Comment: @random: I'm sorry but you shouldn't have closed this. You got it wrong: **Windows 7** has *built-in* capabilities to remote control a Windows Media Player instance on another computer **and** sync files and folders on a network - I don't need additional applications, just having trouble getting those features to work.

Comment: You need to be more explicit then about what your actual problem is. What have you even tried? What are you doing that the dupes don't cover?

Comment: @random: The "dupes" that you refer to are not dupes. They got nothing to do with the question I asked, like I said before I'm not looking for additional software: Windows 7 has those features built-in.

Comment: @random: Regarding being explicit, I think I was if you pay attention. I've tried running the Windows wizards but they didn't seemed to work, I don't know what else you want me to say...