# Networking with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, sync, windows-media-player

I got several computers connected to my home wireless network and I want to make use of some of the features of Windows 7 for home networks but I can't seem to get them working:

1. How do I keep files and folders in sync between specific computers? I'm not talking about Live Sync.
2. How can I stream to Windows Media Player from another computer?

I would appreciate if someone could provide me some links / solutions that address my needs. Thanks!

---

To anyone who thinks this question is a duplicate and wants to close it please bare in mind the following:

- I'm not looking for additional software, I know I can use Live Sync, Dropbox and so on but I'm asking this: how do I configure Windows 7 to sync files between my home network - no Internet required! This has something to do with shared folders and offline files in Windows 7, but I can't get it to work.

**PS**: Please merge with this question: [Networking with Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/139763/networking-with-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Before you can sync files between two computers you have to establish a partnership. This is done in the Sync Centre in Control Panel.

To create a partnership, map a network drive to the computer you wish to sync with, then select which ever folder you wish to sync, right click and choose 'always available offline' these files can then be managed in the 'Manage Offline files' section of Sync centre.

Whilst it is possible to manage synchronisation this way, you would be better of using additional software, something like Microsoft's [SyncToy 2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52)

For streaming media to other devices see this link, it has easy instructions for setting up Media Player:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Stream-your-media-to-devices-and-computers-using-Windows-Media-Player

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about Offline Files, a feature that allows you to cache network-shared files locally and sync them automatically with the network server.  It's not quite the same

On one computer, you have to [share a folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Share-files-with-someone).

Then, on the second computer, browse the network and open the shared folder.  After that, [enable offline files and make the shared folder available offline](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Working-with-network-files-when-you-are-offline).

As Pulse mentioned, Microsoft also has some instructions for [streaming your media to other computers using Windows Media Player](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Stream-your-media-to-devices-and-computers-using-Windows-Media-Player).